# How to get data from Laravel nested relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am new to Laravel. I'm having a lot of trouble getting a very-nested relationship to work correctly in laravel.

The wanted behaviour is as follows,

I have 5 Models. `Purchase`, `Inventory`, `Slab`, `Scarting` and `FloorTile`.

I have one to one relation between Purchase and Inventory Models, while inventory have further relation with slab, scarting and floortile.

I have purchase id and want to get data from `inventory` table, then get a `slab_id`, `scarting_id` or `floorTile_id` from `inventory` table and get data from the respective table.

The `slab_id`, `scarting_id` and `floorTile_id` can be multiple against `inventory id`.

I don't know how to get data every iteration.

Purchase Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Inventory;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
    public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Inventory');
    }

}
```

Inventory Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Slab;
use App\Scarting;
use App\FloorTile;
use App\Purchase;
Use App\StandardSize;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    public function purchase()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Purchase');
    }

    public function standatdSize()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\StandardSize');
    }

    public function slab()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Slab');
    }

    public function scarting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Scarting');
    }

    public function floorTile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\FloorTile');
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$purchase = Purchase::where('factoryName', $factoryName)->with('inventory.slab')->get();
```

The result is as follows:

```
{
  "id": 36,
  "fname": "Sama",
  "lname": "Jojo",
  "factoryName": "Sama Inc.",
  "cnic": "3216542",
  "area": "Johar town",
  "city": "Lahore",
  "province": "Punjab",
  "phone1": "45678912345",
  "phone2": "45678912345",
  "inventory_ID": 10,
  "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
  "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
  "inventory": {
    "id": 10,
    "purchase_id": 36,
    "marbleType": "1",
    "totalSquareFt": 25,
    "priceperSquareFt": 230,
    "totalPurchasePrice": 25000,
    "standardSize_ID": "5",
    "salePrice": 250,
    "miliMeter": "6mm",
    "slab_ID": 1,
    "scarting_ID": null,
    "floorTile_ID": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-19 12:11:45",
    "slab": null
  }
}
```

Even there is data available against slab but still its showing NULL.

Comment: Please post your code in text format instead of image.

Comment: What's the result of what you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for ur replies. Code has been updated. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier for you if your records were `slab_id` and not `slab_ID` this way [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) would do it for you, however you have not followed Laravel's naming convention which is fine but you'll have to tell Laravel that you're using your own naming conventions and it will pick it up just fine. I've provided an example below.

```
public function slab()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Slab', 'id', 'slab_ID');
}
```

`$this->hasOne('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

The foreign key is the primary key of the model you're trying to retrieve and the local_key is the reference of what it's called in this model, usually `model_id` and in this case would be `slab_ID`.

`local_key = $this->id` and `foreign_key = App\Slab` in this case.

Comment: I have done exactly you said, but getting this error.

`Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'slabs.slab_ID' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `slabs` where `slabs`.`slab_ID` in (10, 26))`

Comment: This makes no sense. The 3rd argument would `inventory_ID` if anything. The way you have it setup would be for a `belongsTo` relationship.

Comment: I'm really struggling to english today, I know what I'm trying to say I just can't get it out. You sure it wouldn't be `slab_ID` otherwise how would Laravel know the column name?